# Python Selenium implicit wait

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a difference between:

```
self.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

OR

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

Why does this 15 value explicit wait not over-ride the 10 seconds?
Or is it the case once implicit is specified, it ignores the explicit?

```
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
         lambda wd: wd.find_element_by_css_selector('someCSS')  )
```

Any advice?

Comment: One is Java and the other is Python.

Comment: Also implicit wait is a set once wait for page to load.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits

> An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available.

This syntax should be used for python:

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

Implicitly wait behavior is a very low level so it will affect other operations, like explicit waits.

This will work 100 seconds if no such element:

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(100) # seconds
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
         lambda wd: wd.find_element_by_css_selector('someCSS')  )
```

This will work 20 seconds if no such element (need to recheck):

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 11).until(
         lambda wd: wd.find_element_by_css_selector('someCSS')  )
```

This will work 15 seconds if no such element:

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
         lambda wd: wd.find_element_by_css_selector('someCSS')  )
```

Comment: oh, ok thanks! I didn't realise that if implicit is greater, it takes implicit, and if it is equal it adds the implicit + explicit.